# How to do custom marshalling in SendNotifyMessage() to send data between 2 MFC application

Tags: c++, mfc

I need to broadcast User message with text data from one MFC application to many.
I am using SendNotifyMessage() to broadcast but after receiving the data when I try to convert LParam to CString* I am getting bad pointer error.

MSDN says that

"If you send a message in the range below WM_USER to the asynchronous message functions (PostMessage, SendNotifyMessage, and SendMessageCallback), its message parameters cannot include pointers. Otherwise, the operation will fail. The functions will return before the receiving thread has had a chance to process the message and the sender will free the memory before it is used."

and also

"The system only does marshalling for system messages (those in the range 0 to (WM_USER-1)). To send other messages (those >= WM_USER) to another process, you must do **custom marshalling**."

So how to do custom marashalling in C++ to send data to another C++ application?

Comment: You can pass a single value with a message. So you need some form of **[IPC](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365574%28v=vs.85%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396)** if you want to pass more data.

Comment: Sending a pointer *between* different processes is pointless. Each process has its own address space and pointers in one application will not point to anything useful in another application.

Comment: *"Custom marshalling"* is a term used to mean: Transfer data from one process to another process. The system does this for you for standard windows messages. Doing it yourself is rather involved. I'd suggest going with [named pipes](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365594.aspx) instead. But any other type of IPC will do just as well.

Comment: If the data size that is necessary to send from one application to another not too big the **Data Copy** message can be used. An example is provided [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms649009%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

Comment: You can marshal the data to a local database, a shared memory, or a memory block in the target process via WriteProcessMemory.